# DDMS "Can't bind to local 8612 for debugger" in Android Studio 1.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio, ddms, genymotion

I want to pull a file from `genymotion` virtual machine with `DDMS`, but in my `Android Studio` platform, I can only read `sdcard` file and is unable to see file in `sdcard`, the console log `[2015-01-05 09:34:03 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8612 for debugger`.

Comment: you have eclipse run in background? or another device that connect to computer?

Comment: @MaorHadad no, I do not know why. But when I close Android Studio, it is ok

Answer (score 2):

Usually the port would be blocked, restarting Android Studio would help here!

Comment: yes, I tried this lately that day, this problem is outdate.